# How can I extract year from strptime?

Tags: r, datetime

I have times in this format:

```
t <- "4/2/2004 12:45"

I can extract day and month using these two lines:

strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$day
strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$mday
```

But this doesn't give me the years I want. I gives me year without the century:

```
strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$year
```

How can I get the year exactly? Like 1987, 2012 etc. And not 87 and 12.

If there is any other function to use for this, I am OK with that as well.

Comment: `year(strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC"))#[1] 2004`

Comment: @akrun isn't that a `lubridate` function?

Comment: I didn't load lubridate, but `data.table` and `dplyr` is loaded

Comment: ah, that's a `data.table` function as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add 1900. See the *Details* section of `?POSIXlt` for, um, details.

```
> tm <- "4/2/2004 12:45"
> strptime(tm, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$year
[1] 104
> strptime(tm, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$year + 1900
[1] 2004
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `lubridate` for all your intuitive timestamp processing needs:

```
library(lubridate)
t <- "4/2/2004 12:45"
t2 <- mdy_hm(t) # parsing format: month-day-year_hour-minute
day(t2)
yday(t2)
year(t2)
```

Comment: This is good. Can you tell me if Lubridate is the suggested method for doing all datetime related processing?

Comment: `lubridate` makes parsing and handling dates and times a lot easier and helps cut down on user error by using simple and understandable syntax. There's no "suggested method" but I find it incredibly useful and it is a popular package.

Answer (score 3):

Using base package:

```
t <- "4/2/2004 12:45"
as.numeric(format(as.Date(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC"), "%Y"))
```

result is:

```
[1] 2004
```