# extracting hour minute from non-delimited data

Tags: r, datetime

I have instrument data that contains hours and minutes in a non-delimited format (e.g., `0, 30, 100, 130, ... 2300, 2300`). I would like to convert the column to a [`POSIX`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) object in R (e.g., something that looks like `"2016-01-07 11:07:59 EST"`) and my first step is to extract out the hour and minute data from this column. (I also have a corresponding Julian date and Year columns.)

I am getting tripped up because the hour and minutes are not delimited and I have been unable to use the `strptime` function. I have searched using both Google and SO (using the `R` and `datatime` tags on SO), but have been unable to find a solution. All of the examples I could find on SO (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494216/extract-date-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973673/how-can-i-extract-year-from-strptime)) have the hour and minute separated by something such as `0:30`.

Here is my MCVE:

```
hour <- c(0, 30, 100, 130, 1000, 1030, 2300, 2330)
year <- c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007)
day  <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
strptime(hour, "%h%m")
```

So, how do I extract out the hour and minute when I have non-delimited data?

Comment: This gets close....but ignores minutes. Also, not sure how to interpret minutes. Is 100 - 1:00 or 10:00? as.POSIXct(paste(year, day, hour, sep = ':'), format = '%Y:%d:%H')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to add leading 0s to hours that have less than 4 digits:

```
strptime(sprintf("%04d", hour), "%H%M")
```

You can then convert it to a date:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(year,day,sprintf("%04d", hour),sep="-"),format = '%Y-%j-%H%M')
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the `sprintf` function. That was key! (I also saw your comment before you deleted it).

Answer (score 4):

Use `sprintf`:

```
as.POSIXct(sprintf("%d %d %04d", year, day, hour), "%Y %j %H%M", tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2007-01-02 00:00:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 00:30:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 01:00:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 01:30:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 10:00:00 GMT"
#[6] "2007-01-02 10:30:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 23:00:00 GMT" "2007-01-02 23:30:00 GMT"
```

Note that julian days are specified with `%j` and not `%d`.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to pad the hour with enough 0 with 'str_pad' from 'stringr' and then use 'strptime':

```
tmp <- stringr::str_pad(hour,4,"left","0")
strptime(tmp, "%H%M")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
hour <- c(0, 30, 100, 130, 1000, 1030, 2300, 2330)
year <- c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007)
day  <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

mins <- substr(sprintf('%04d', hour), 3, 4)
hour <- substr(sprintf('%04d', hour), 1, 2)

as.POSIXct(paste(year, day, hour, mins, sep = ':'), format = '%Y:%d:%H:%M')

[1] "2007-01-02 00:00:00 EST" "2007-01-02 00:30:00 EST"
[3] "2007-01-02 01:00:00 EST" "2007-01-02 01:30:00 EST"
[5] "2007-01-02 10:00:00 EST" "2007-01-02 10:30:00 EST"
[7] "2007-01-02 23:00:00 EST" "2007-01-02 23:30:00 EST"
```